# How to see if there is a printing task running on KDE?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, printing

I am using KDE on Archlinux. I found that when I print a big file using okular, there is no notification whether the printing task is finished or not. Instead on Windows there is a printing icon on the taskbar. How to see if there is a printing task running on KDE?